# QFileSystemModel - How do I list only contents of certain subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview

For example if I set my rootPath to /x/y/z/USA, and here's the directories under USA.

```
USA
|--other
|--other
|--state
    |-- California
    |-- Florida
```

I want my QTreeView to display USA, and under USA display subdirectories under *state* without showing *state* itself and ignore the *other* directories.

```
USA
|--California
|--Florida
```

Is this possible with QFileSystemModel? Could anyone give me some example please?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not set the path to `/x/y/z/USA/state`?

Comment: There are multiple projects that I want the user to be able to navigate. So there may be USA, India, etc, each projects are sharing the same basic structure. This application would browse only a specific aspect of them.

Comment: This doesn't make it any clearer to me. I suspect you may be suffering from [The XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Regardless, I don't think what you want can be done without serious subclassing of `QFileSystemModel`.

Comment: It might be possible to do something with [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html), but it probably won't be easy. Why don't you just re-organise the file structure, instead?

Comment: There are other aspects of the project stored as well which I want to selectively expose in my treeview.

I've been separating this into multiple listwidget and combobox in my previous scripts. Trying to see if I can collapse them all into 1 treeview.